# AWS C++ SDK, How to send a a custom email using SES?

Tags: c++, qt, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send and email from my **Qt / C++ application** using the **sendRawEmail function of the AWS / SES** library. I will use this function because I will have to send emails with attached documents.

**I tried  this code but it doesn't work... Please, someone could help me ?**

```
Aws::SES::Model::SendRawEmailRequest sendRawEmailRequest;

DestinationsVector.emplace_back(email_contact.toStdString().c_str());
sendRawEmailRequest.SetDestinations(DestinationsVector);

sendRawEmailRequest.SetSource(email_contact.toStdString().c_str());

QString rawMsg;
QTextStream rawMsgStream(&rawMsg);
rawMsgStream << "From: " <<  email_contact << "\\n";
rawMsgStream << "To: " << email_contact << "\\n";
rawMsgStream << "Subject: " << "my Title" <<"\\n";
rawMsgStream << "MIME-Version: 1.0\\n";
rawMsgStream << "Content-type: multipart/related; boundary=\"NextPart\"\\n";
rawMsgStream << "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\\n";
rawMsgStream << "\\n--NextPart\\n";
rawMsgStream << "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\\n ";
rawMsgStream << "My message" << "\\n--NextPart--\\n";

QByteArray buff64 = rawMsg.toLocal8Bit().toBase64();
Aws::Utils::ByteBuffer buff((const unsigned char*)buff64.toStdString().c_str(),buff64.size());

Aws::SES::Model::RawMessage rm;
rm.SetData(buff);
sendRawEmailRequest.SetRawMessage(rm);

auto outcome = _clientEmailService->SendRawEmail(sendRawEmailRequest);
if (outcome.IsSuccess()){
   return tr("Email sent!");
}
else {
   outcome.GetError().GetMessage().c_str();
   return outcome.GetError().GetMessage().c_str();
}
```

Here you are the failure reason sent by Amazon SES:

```
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-5.7.1 [54.240.8.64      11] Our system has detected that this message is not
 550-5.7.1 RFC 5322 compliant:
 550-5.7.1 'From' header is missing.
 550-5.7.1 To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, this message has been
 550-5.7.1 blocked. Please visit
 550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=RfcMessageNonCompliant
 550 5.7.1 and review RFC 5322 specifications for more information.    51-v6si822773qvt.246 - gsmtp
 Status: 5.7.1
```

Comment: What happens when you run it, error messages? Also, what have you already done in SES/IAM to make this work?

Comment: The error tells you what's wrong - you're not following the RFC.  But you're making this harder than it needs to be.  Why not use a [library](https://github.com/cutelyst/simple-mail) that is already built?

Comment: Hello Matt D. The sendRawEmail execution is a success but I receive a failure status email from Amazon SES as written in my post. In the IAM configuration, I set the authorisation in order to use the SES functions.

Comment: Hello Stdunbar, Yes But the issue indicated by Amazon is wrong, I have the From tag in my message. Actually I use this [library](https://github.com/bluetiger9/SmtpClient-for-Qt), it is working but I think it is not very good for these reasons : 1-I don't know the "quality" of this source code and functionalities embedded 2-could be obsolete. 3-I already use AWS services for many others functions.                                                                        Thanks for the link, this lib seems to be more recent.